# How I include learners in mlr3

Tags: nnet, mlr3

I am using rpart library in mlr3, but when I am changing it to other learners like nnet, it gives me error that not found in DictionaryLearner. In my code, only rpart is working and all other learners like nnet, svm gives error.

I am using the following code

```
library(mlr3)
library(mlr3tuning)
library(paradox)


df=readARFF("nasa93.arff")
task=TaskRegr$new("df", df, target = "act_effort") 
#task = tsk("pima")
#learner = lrn("classif.rpart")
learner= lrn("regr.rpart")
```

Comment: Please don't edit the question to be something completely different. Ask a new question instead.

Comment: I tried but I have been blocked from further questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all available learners in the `mlr_learners` dictionary (which is where the `lrn()` command will look them up). `mlr3` only comes with a basic set of learners; additional ones are available when you load the `mlr3learners` and `mlr3extralearners` packages.

Comment: thank you. But when I install mlr3extralearners (e.g. install.packages("mlr3extralearners"), it gives error that the package is not available.

Comment: See https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners -- it's not on CRAN.

Comment: I believe `mlr3extralearners` is only available on Github. You can install it with `devtools::install_github("https://github.com/mlr-org/mlr3extralearners")`. You can install `mlr3learners` from CRAN though. Here's a list of all learners and packages you can get them from -- https://mlr3extralearners.mlr-org.com/articles/learners/learner_status.html.

Comment: Thank you Lars and damir, I have installed and loaded the mlr3extralearners but still it gives me the error: learner= lrn("regr.nnet") , Error: Element with key 'regr.nnet' not found in DictionaryLearner!

Comment: You need to load `mlr3learners`. Please read the package Readme to know which learners are living in which package.